# Javascript clock with variable timezone

Tags: javascript, datetime

I have a clock like so:

```
const timeContainer = document.querySelector('.timeContainer');

var showTime = (timeZone) => {
  let utcTime = new Date().toUTCString();
  //need to subtract/add timezone from utcTime
  //need to remove everything except for time e.g. 00:22:22
  return utcTime;
};

setInterval( () => {
  timeContainer.innerHTML = showTime('-8');
}, 1000);
```

Which gives me GMT time like this:

```
Tue, 29 Nov 2016 00:35:54 GMT
```

.. which is what I want! But say I want to get the time in Hong Kong, and also *only* the numerical time, none of the date and timezone information.

I basically need to:

**a)** subtract/add a variable `timeZone` integer from `utcTime`

**b)** remove all text in output except for the time, e.g. `utcTime` only outputs as `00:22:22`

I basically need to generate a clock based on what `timeZone` integer I run `showTime` with, for example:

```
showTime(-5);
//returns time in EST timezone
showTime(-6);
//returns time in CST timezone
```

etc. Is there a way to do this using `.toUTCString()`? Or is there a better method?

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pvhbgsbL) with my code.

Comment: I suggest that you consider using [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone).

Comment: What is your question or issue then?

Comment: edited my question for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the timestamp which is time since the epoch in UTC, offset by the desired timezone and build the string.

```
const timeContainer = document.querySelector('.timeContainer');

var dateToTimeString = (dt) => {
  let hh = ('0' + dt.getUTCHours()).slice(-2);
  let mm = ('0' + dt.getUTCMinutes()).slice(-2);
  let ss = ('0' + dt.getUTCSeconds()).slice(-2);
  return hh + ':' + mm + ':' + ss;
}

var showTime = (timeZone) => {
  // convert timezone in hours to milliseconds
  let tzTime = new Date(Date.now() + timeZone * 3600000);
  return dateToTimeString(tzTime);
};

setInterval( () => {
  timeContainer.innerHTML = showTime('-8');
}, 1000);
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/25u117v0/2/)

Which will output

```
17:00:00
```

Comment: Ah, sorry if it wasn't clear enough. I want to be able to put in any sort of timezone modifier and easily generate the time at that location. for instance if I ran showTime(-5) I would get EST, showTime(-6) CST, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the time in the "11/29/2016" format you can use toLocaleDateString() instead of toUTCString().

If you want the time in the "Tue Nov 29 2016" format you can use toDateString() instead of toUTCString().